# Configure test accounts using Secret Manager tool to set a password

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

I have downloaded the project from the link shared in this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/secure-data?view=aspnetcore-5.0):

https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/tree/main/aspnetcore/security/authorization/secure-data/samples/final3

Followed the steps mentioned in the article to set password for test accounts (admin, manager). Used the below command in PowerShell:

```
dotnet user-secrets set SeedUserPW Password@123
```

```
Successfully saved SeedUserPW = Password@123 to the secret store.
```

Build the project and run it. Still not able to login using *admin@contoso.com* and password used in PowerShell.

[image: Login-Error]